# how transform works in actionscript or flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

[image]

I have component which is been created in 3D shape. to this component I would like add a button. Since component is created in 3D view, if I add component into the 3D view,button won't show up.

After digging many API, I came across with transform and Matrix.

As per my understanding, I have followed this approach

1) From 3D view component,  got matrix object

eg: `var matrix2D:Matrix = transform.matrix`;

2) then applied, this matrix to button transform

eg: var button:Button = new Button();

```
   button.transform.matrix = matrix2D.
```

it did not worked, Am I following right approach. pleas guide me

Thanks

Comment: Are you working in 3d or 2d view? Your question is not clear

Comment: it is 3D view, i think image clears this point!

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your button to 3D object and place it in the same way you place the first one.

Comment: Could u pls explore it with example